# Cisco 5512-x TCP request discarded

Tags: firewall, cisco, nat

We have a fairly basic ACL and NAT rule allowing RDP inbound and NAT'd to a LAN IP (all IPs replaced with **IP**)

```
object network STATIC-PAT-RDP
 host IP
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object TerminalServices any object IP log debugging
access-list OUTSIDE-IN remark Allow RDP
access-list OUTSIDE-IN extended permit tcp any object STATIC-PAT-RDP eq 3389

object network STATIC-PAT-RDP
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 3389 3389
access-group OUTSIDE-IN in interface outside
```

However, the connection is being dropped when it hits the WAN Interface:

```
7   May 05 2015 11:37:56        IP  4335    IP  3389    TCP request discarded from IP to outside:IP
```

I've personally never seen this before - the device is listening on 3389 via a netstat -ano and I can RDP internally.